# Sqlite net plc in Xamarin form: how do i commit the .db with async insert/update

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

I'm able to get the .db data and set into sqlite properties to query asynchronously. How do I go about in updating and inserting changes into the db afterwards? Do I have to make a synchronous database connection?

Comment: This is pretty clearly explained in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases#data-manipulation-methods

Comment: @Joey there is also one article about [insert or update data in sqlite](https://xamarinmonkeys.blogspot.com/2019/02/xamarinforms-sqlite-database-crud.html), please take a look.

Comment: Yes, when running my program, I'm able to see the data and results of the query functions, but my .db file doesn't look like it updated from its created previous date. Therefore, do I have to open a synchronous connection and update or is it possible to do the change when I call the asynchronous querying function?

Comment: Yes, you can use async functions.  If you have a specific problem, post the details of that problem.